# Join a Pandas dataframe with dataframe of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, spyder

As illustrated below, I have two panda dataframes that I want to combine. 
The first holds information on a huge number of products. The second holds the information of the category of the product where each entry in the category column is a list.

```
   CatId   Date           CatId      CatName
0     C2   01-15       0     C1   [crime, alt]
1     C1   01-15       1     C2   [crime, bests]
2     C1   01-15       2     C3   [fantasy, american]
3     C3   01-16       
.
.
n     C2   02-17
```

I am interested in the following dataframe:

```
      CatId             Date           
0  [crime, bests]       01-15      
1  [crime, alt]         01-15      
2  [crime, alt]         01-15      
3  [fantasy, american]  01-16       
.
.
n  [crime, bests]       02-17
```

For efficiency (due to the size of the dataset) I try to avoid looping.

Is it possible in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by Series created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
print (df1)
  CatId   Date
0    C2  01-15
1    C1  01-15
2    C1  01-15
3    C3  01-16
n    C2  02-17

print (df2)

  CatId              CatName
0    C1         [crime, alt]
1    C2       [crime, bests]
2    C3  [fantasy, american]

df1['CatId'] = df1['CatId'].map(df2.set_index('CatId')['CatName'])
print (df1)
                 CatId   Date
0       [crime, bests]  01-15
1         [crime, alt]  01-15
2         [crime, alt]  01-15
3  [fantasy, american]  01-16
n       [crime, bests]  02-17
```

Comment: Worked perfect, jezrael. Thanks a lot